# Selectable (multiple) + sortable advanced

Tags: jquery

I would like to know how I can do this effect (see video): http://vimeo.com/18819265

It's a sortable + selectable, with an effect showing the number of elements moving.

Selectable: Elements can be selected one by one, or with multiple group with shift key clicked
Sortable: You can drag those elements and leave them in other place, with effect of showing number of elements moved.

Yes, I do know jQuery UI, but they have separated effects. I've Googling around but I don't find anything similar.

jQueryUI Selectable (jqueryui.com/demos/selectable/#default) does not have the multiple selection with shift key, selecting all elements between the firstly selected one, and the one you are. They have an effect to select all elements included in a box you draw with the mouse, but this effect should override the draggable effect.

jQuery Sortable (jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#display-grid) does not have multiple selection as shown in video.

Also, the effect of showing number of elements moving, is cool :)

I found this: interface.eyecon.ro/demos/sort_floats.html

But you can not do multiple selection :(

Anyone ? :P

Comment: I would try breaking this up into several smaller questions.  You're asking for a lot of coding without any initial start to what is actually multiple problems.