# New HTML User Interfaces achieved with the help of jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, user-interface

Consider a scenario. I have to select multiple categories and submit to database. The orthodox method is to provide checkboxes. But we can have a colorful method by using the following steps:

•   Create an ordered list with inline-block display style

•   Using jQUery UI, make it as “Selectable” widget.

Now I can see all items in a better visualization and select (multiple) required items before submit.

```
$("#myOrderedListSelecatableAsHeaderPart").selectable();
```

Refer: [jQuery Selectable Customization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9208849/jquery-selectable-customization)

In effect, it becomes a new control. Similarly, **what are the other changes brought in by utilizing jQuery features?**

Comment: What is the question? Are you worried about side effects of jQuery, or fishing for ideas what can be done with jQuery?

Comment: I am not worried about such a helpful library. :-) I am trying to find out enhanced user experience that can be achieved using jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That question can't really be answered in a concise way. jQuery is a toolkit where, for instance, [.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/), can be applied to most css values making your imagination the limit for what effects can be done. This is even more true with all CSS3 things happening.

Many pre-packaged effects use methods like `animate()` under the hood.

That said, here are a couple of sites to get your inspiration going, many also provide the effects as packaged up code:

- [jQuery style](http://jquerystyle.com/)
- [Use jQuery](http://usejquery.com/sites)
- [jQuery List](http://jquerylist.com/)